# Rails displaying a string with CR and spaces

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called MSG and it has a content:string in it.

In the MSG form I have a

```
<%= f.text_area :content %>
```

for the user to input the message.

However, when I display :content using <%= Msg.content %> the text has no "enter"/CR or spaces, tabs etcs and it is just a long line of text.

How do I force displaying the CR that that user put?

example:

content:

```
Hello,
buy milk.
```

instead I get

```
Hello, buy milk.
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `simple_format` to properly display line breaks:

```
<%= simple_format(Msg.content) %>
```

Comment: It sounded like he wanted to format the output after the user enters it, not the text area itself.

Comment: i use simple_format h(MSG.content) to avoid any XSS situations